# Where'd my chicken find the Space Jump?

Tags: guacamelee

I just noticed that as a chicken I have infinite double jumps. I know for sure this didn't exist when Pollo Power was first obtained, and I'm pretty sure the getting the actual Double Jump didn't unlock it either. So where did it come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I found out where this came from.

> Collecting the five Orbs of Chac Mool causes the game to show a tip of "You feel lighter.". This is when the chicken form gets infinite double jumps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually infinite jump in Pollo Power comes after collecting orbs in game. There are about 7 of them.

They are located in:

1. Juan's Casa(house)
2. Forest ( in the cave with skull switch from where you will have to
   do goat fly towards the left till you hit an obstacle in mid air)
3. The mines next to Santa Luchia after completing the third set of
   challenges
4. In the Seriaa right at the beginning (you enter a big room with a
   way up. Instead of going up just use Goat Fly to go straight towards
   the right till you reach disappearing blocks)
5. Treetops and honestly this is the hardest of the lot. Might take
   some time to complete this one.
6. In the desert, when going underground you find a blocked door with a
   man standing in front of it who will ask if you want to buy some
   magic explosives. Buy it and use it on the door. Then use Change
   Dimension power to see unblocked door and enter it. You will find El
   Inferno. There you need to get at least 10 out of 13 golds in the
   challenges to open the Devils room. (The Devil has been turned into
   a chicken by the game's villain) the Devil then rewards you by
   showing the door to Chak Mool where you get the orb
7. By defeating the final boss CALACA. (As you get the final piece the
   mask will begin to shine which means its full power is activated)

After this is done and end credits is shown, you will return to the game. Just use Pollo Power and keep pressing space to keep flying.

Comment: Is this from a different version of the game than the Gold Edition on Steam? As I said in my answer, I only had to collect five orbs.

Comment: I also played the Gold Edition, and the Devil did not reward you with an orb (only a new costume). There are also 17 golds in that edition. I got the power up after collecting 5, although I had already completed the game, so I'm not sure if it remembered that 6th one or not (but judging by Toomai's comment, that one isn't necessary).