# What is meant by "You feel lighter" when you get all the mask pieces / orbs in Guacamelee?

Tags: guacamelee

After collecting all but one of the hidden mask orbs in Guacamelee, you are told that you "Feel lighter" what does that mean?  I figured it meant that you could jump higher but I couldn't tell a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this question points out, [Where'd my chicken find the Space Jump?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/128798/37419) you are given infinite jumps whenever you use your chicken transformation power after collecting all the available orbs in the game (besides the one after beating the game).

Answer (score 1):

**You feel lighter** means that you have unlocked the 'Chicken Fly' ability. By continually mashing the jump button in Pollo form you can fly. It kinda breaks the game as you can pretty much go anywhere with it and it makes some of the more tricky platforming sections a complete doddle.